# Cloud Function + VPC connector through VPN with one Intenal IP (LAN)

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-vpc, google-cloud-vpn

I have this problem: I need to request some 3rd party HTTP resource through a VPN from a Cloud Function. The counterpart can route only one IP as an origin of the requests but the VPC connector attached to Cloud Function is /28 CIDR so I don't know what IP of that range is gonna use to tell counterpart to add it in the route of VPN traffic.

Maybe I can use some internal NAT / proxy to forward that traffic but I want to solve with some native or cleaner solution.

I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to find a third party solution which does the proxy process in order to avoid the /28 range of the VPC Connector and send traffic with an unique and known IP address. Although it'd be interesting I haven't find it. Going to keep looking and let you know if I can find a solution or workaround.